# Save Excel File as Text in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, text-files, xlsx

I'm trying to open a (.xls) file and save it as a text file through Microsoft access. Can't work out why this is throwing a wobbly.

```
Dim xlApp As Object 

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True

Dim strFile As String, Table As String Dim wbk As Object

Set wbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Test.xls")
ChDir "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop"
```

The following line is red and gives me the error "Expected Named Parameter"

```
wbk.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Test.txt", _
FileFormat:=xltextwindows, CreateBackup:=False** 

Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Is xltextwindows from excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Object Browser:

```
Const xlTextWindows = 20 (&H14)
  Element of Excel.XlFileFormat
```

If you haven't set a reference to the Excel Object library (as suggested by your use of late binding), you need to add this declaration in your code:

```
Const xlTextWindows = 20
```